# Clean Architecture - obtaining cached data while refreshing it using repository pattern and use cases

Tags: android, design-patterns, repository-pattern, use-case, clean-architecture

I have one question of best practice. I'm trying to apply Clean Architecture in a sample app using MVVM. My question  is, if ViewModel is supposed to call the use cases instead of calling directly the Repository (which has access to database and the API), but I want to display the cached results while the information is being refresh, how is supposed the ViewModel to access to the cached data if it's using the use case and not the repository?

I read [this post](https://proandroiddev.com/why-you-need-use-cases-interactors-142e8a6fe576) and [Android official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#cache-data) but I'm not sure which is the best way of achieving this behaviour.

Comment: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/7686abc4bba087c8ee02f0ac569093bf304245e6/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt

Comment: but here the view is using directly the ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Considering separation of concerns, I like to implement caching using decorator pattern. Depending on your concrete implementation a decorator around the repository or around the use case interactor could be a solution.

Comment: But if you use a decorator pattern, then for example the repository would have to espose a method to retrieve the information from the cache wouldn't it? That is the use case of initialisation, when you first want to obtain the cached data

Comment: The interface of the decorator should not change. The caching repository just always returns cached data. The implementation of the caching decorator might have dependencies to an external cache implementation.